# Sending-receiving collection over RabbitMQ in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

Assume the config, applied both on sending and receiving sides:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class EventsConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter) {
        final var rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

Assume also, that there is a simple Spring Boot RabbitMQ listener on receiving side, declared like:

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = "${amqp.inbox}")
    public void listen(org.springframework.amqp.core.Message message) {
        ...
    }
```

Attempt to receive a collection of `List<TaskAssignment>` (where `TaskAssignment` is a simple POJO having two UUIDs), sent by rabbit template, is ended on receiver side with exception:

```
accounting-service_1  | 01:26:39.610 WARN  [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy] - Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'[{"assigneeId":"1033c1ab-f277-4162-a711-722966bf69ec","taskId":"ae408e2d-39e0-4094-bf52-8c171d965be7"}]' MessageProperties [headers={__ContentTypeId__=java.lang.Object, __TypeId__=io.vavr.collection.List$Cons}, messageId=83f6bb30-a2b8-434a-867e-08684241e9b0, type=TASKS_REASSIGNED, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=outbox, receivedRoutingKey=, deliveryTag=3, consumerTag=amq.ctag-PodhhDJx6JtYsjIg6Cof1Q, consumerQueue=accounting-service])
accounting-service_1  | 01:26:39.610 ERROR [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception
accounting-service_1  | org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:146)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1460)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1744)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1519)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:968)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:914)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1289)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195)
accounting-service_1  |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
accounting-service_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:146)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1656)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1575)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1563)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1554)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
accounting-service_1  |     ... 6 common frames omitted
accounting-service_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:294)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:271)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:251)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:344)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:347)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:229)
accounting-service_1  |     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:136)
accounting-service_1  |     ... 11 common frames omitted
accounting-service_1  | Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
accounting-service_1  |  at [Source: (String)"[{"assigneeId":"1033c1ab-f277-4162-a711-722966bf69ec","taskId":"ae408e2d-39e0-4094-bf52-8c171d965be7"}]"; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: byte[][0])
accounting-service_1  |     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
```

Vavr module for Jackson is installed in `ObjectMapper`, so the root cause is not the fact that the collection is wrong and unserializable.

Notable thing about the stack trace is the headers part:

```
headers={__ContentTypeId__=java.lang.Object, __TypeId__=io.vavr.collection.List$Cons}
```

My theory is: since listener has received a JSON array, and Jackson requires explicit `TypeReference` to be provided in order to deduce a POJO, to which to deserialize array's items, that was the reason failure occurred in `Jackson2MessageConverter`. Nobody have given it the contents type.

The question is - how to provide `Jackson2MessageConverter` with such info? `RabbitTemplate` doesn't seem to give any means. Explicit setup of `__ContentTypeId__` on sender side doesn't help either.

Or how to at least overcome Jackson deserialization on receiving side and listen to just raw messages in `@RabbitListener` with `byte[]` payload?

UPD: made a project reproducing the issue here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rde9u02mxob189w/proba_amqp.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to receive the raw, unconverted `Message`.

Try `listen(List<Foo> foos)` instead so we can pass the inferred type to the converter.

**EDIT**

The issue is that your collection object is not compatible with Jackson.

This works

```java
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<POJO> payload = new ArrayList<>();
        payload.add(new POJO(1,2));
        payload.add(new POJO(3,4));
        //POJO payload = new POJO(1,2);
        template.convertAndSend(
            outbox,
            "",
            payload,
            message -> {
                var props = message.getMessageProperties();
                props.setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                return message;
            }
        );
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${amqp.inbox}")
    public void listen(List<POJO> pojos) {
        System.out.println("Message reached:" + pojos);
    }
```

```
Message reached:[com.skapral.POJO@7af8fa38, com.skapral.POJO@5569d76c]
```

**FROM AUTHOR:**
This answer gave me a hint towards the root cause. It turns out there is the bug in `vavr-jackson` - Jackson module for supporting Vavr collections.

https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr-jackson/issues/189

Comment: I tried, but result was the same (apart from the headers. `__ContentTypeId__` had a concrete type of list, but the payload wasn't deserialized anyway). Also, even if it is raw (which I am totally okay with) - I wonder why there was an attempts to deserialize the JSON, instead of returning just raw bytes?

Comment: The issue is that the `io.vavr` collection is not compatible with Jackson - see the edit.

Comment: `java.util.List.of` (Java 9) works too, as long as you receive `List<POJO>` in the listener, and not just the raw unconverted message.

Comment: > The issue is that the io.vavr collection is not compatible with Jackson 

There is "vavr-jackson" module, that adds Jackson support for vavr, and I am using it successfully in all other places, like HTTP endpoints responses. The problem is definitely neither in vavr, nor in Jackson, I have already checked this.


If interested, you can find a minimal project for reproducting the issue in my discussion with Artem Bilan (duplicated it in the issue description).

Comment: Oh. Didn't noticed you've quoted it already in the answer. My bad. Let me recheck

Comment: Ok, the provided alternative works, but I still don't get why the reason is Vavr collection. Since vavr support is enabled in `JacksonConfig`, I don't believe that the root cause is in Jackson support absence. I'll take some time to debug the case before accepting the answer. Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the vavr deserializer - see `at io.vavr.jackson.datatype.deserialize.SerializableDeserializer.deserialize(SerializableDeserializer.java:43) ~[vavr-jackson-0.10.3.jar:na]` in the stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too: https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr-jackson/issues/189

Answer (score 1):

See if this sample helps you somehow:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/main/spring-rabbit-json

The docs is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#json-message-converter

**UPDATE**

See what would be a difference if you use this option on the converter:

```
/**
 * When false (default), fall back to type id headers if the type (or contents of a container
 * type) is abstract. Set to true if conversion should always be attempted - perhaps because
 * a custom deserializer has been configured on the {@link ObjectMapper}. If the attempt fails,
 * fall back to headers.
 * @param alwaysAttemptConversion true to attempt.
 * @since 2.2.8
 */
public void setAlwaysConvertToInferredType(boolean alwaysAttemptConversion) {
```

Comment: Unfortunalely, it didn't. No matter how I try sending the list, or defining an annotated listener in order to receive it, it didn't help. I managed to fix wrong "__ContentTypeId__" header, but it didn't help. I see how it might be possible by using `rabbitTemplate::receiveAndConvert`, but I'd rather leave it as a last resort.

Comment: Debugging the case, I faced that all paths come into `AbstractJackson2MessageConverter::convertContent` method (l. 300 on Spring AMQP v.2.3.10). Inside it, the only branch that leads to `objectMapper.readValue` with ParameterizedType, is branch where `conversionHint` is not null.

Comment: However, observing the call stack, it looks for me like that it all comes from `AbstractJackson2MessageConverter::fromMessage(Message message)` method, which just unconditionally provides null `conversionHint`.

Comment: It is even possible to listen for the collections by `@RabbitListener`?

Comment: In addition, one thing that causes more misunderstanding is: why it even started deserializing the JSON there? In listener there is just plain `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message`, with `byte[]` payload, why not just returning the plain bytes payload there?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: I gave it a try. Unfortunately, changing this option doesn't change anything. I forgot to tell last time that `inferredType` from l.304 in my case is always `null`, which means that condition on l.309 will be false no matter what the option value is.

Comment: Any chances to have some simple project from you to play with?

Comment: Yeah, sure. It'll take some time though

Comment: See a comment in the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`: `/*
     * We're looking for a single parameter, or one annotated with @Payload.
     * We ignore parameters with type Message because they are not involved with conversion.
     */`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239136/discussion-between-skapral-and-artem-bilan).